# How do I control the select sql of a has_many in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, has-many

Rails version used: 4.2.1

So basically I have a model in which I want either of the relational ids, in this case `competitors.company_id` OR `competitors.competitor_id` to match positive as a relation through a has_many relation. The select for such a query is actually really simple and I just need the has_many to produce it in order for this kind of relation to work correctly. The SQL I am trying to produce is:

```
SELECT "competitors".* FROM "competitors" WHERE ("competitors".company_id = 101 or "competitors".competitor_id = 101)
```

What is actually being produced by this relation is:

```
SELECT "competitors".* FROM "competitors" WHERE ("competitors".company_id = 101 or "competitors".competitor_id = 101) FROM "competitors" WHERE "competitors"."company_id" = $1
```

Obviously there is an additional `FROM` and `WHERE` being added to the query which shouldn't be there. How would I go about making this kind of relation work correctly with a has_many relation?

Model 1:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :competitors, -> (object){ select "\"competitors\".* FROM \"competitors\" WHERE (\"competitors\".company_id = #{object.id} or \"competitors\".competitor_id = #{object.id}" }
end
```

Model 2:

```
class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :competitor, class_name: "Company"
end
```

Thank you for the help and I can provide any additional details needed in order to get to an answer.

Comment: you need to overload the where clouse with just "competitors.competitor_id = #{object.id}", NOT the select clouse so the ORM adds from and where clouses

Comment: You cannot remove this from has_many - what is the point if it does not generate WHERE "competitors"."company_id" = $1. Why do not you just add scopes with params to Competitors model and then just have a method inside company that gives you Competitors based on your OR statement like Competitor.filter self.id ) where filter is custom scope with lambda operator: scope :filter, -> (company_id) { where("company_id = ? OR id = ?") }

Comment: @MirzaMemic I was hoping to keep the caching benefits of having a real relation between these models, but I guess it won't be possible.

Comment: Well for caching there are ways to implement it. One thing that I would definitely avoid is having the lambda operator inside has_many, competitors, -> (object){ select...but you can still have caching for your custom method